# Отличие регулярных выражений

Tags: регулярные-выражения, php

Здравствуйте.

PHP довольно долго знаю, но регулярных выржениях вроде знаю, но сам синтаксис не пойму.
Например, не пойму, чем отличается

```
preg_replace("!jhj(.*?)hg!si","hgfh",$string);
```

от

```
preg_replace("/jhj(.*?)hg/si","hgfh",$string);
```

от

```
preg_replace("/jhj(.*?)hg/i","hgfh",$string);
```

Возможно, не там спрашиваю, но не знаете, где подробно пишут о рег. выражениях.

Спасибо.

Answer (score 1):

В последнем выражении не используется модификатор `/s (PCRE_DOTALL)` который в шаблоне соответствует всем символам, включая перевод строк. Т.е. в выражении 1 и 2 `*` соответствует всем символам за исключением пробельных, а в выражении 3 пробельные символы включены в набор.

Comment: Думаю, `*` -> `.*`?

Answer (score 0):

Тем, что в одном использован разделитель / , а в другом -- !

На работу это влиять не должно. Разделители выбираются из соображений читабельность. Внутри выражения символ, используемый в качестве разделителя, должен экранироваться